# 2013 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Programmers' [third moderator election](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: World Engineer]

He'll be joining [the existing crew](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank him for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice as he learns the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/958001/0).

I also wish to announce that veteran moderator [Josh K](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/2654) is stepping down after two years. Moderating a site as *spirited* as Programmers can be a thankless job at times, so please join me now in thanking him for his service, and wishing him all the best on the next leg of his pilgrimage.

Comment: Congratulations to World Engineer. I'm sure you'll make a good moderator.

Comment: Congratulations World Engineer!  I am glad that I am now no longer the Freshman Moderator because I was starting to tire from all of the hazing ;-)

Comment: Many thanks as well to JoshK for his years of service!

Comment: Congrats @WorldEngineer! I'm sure you'll do the job amazingly!

Comment: Will @JoshK log in to say 'Goodbye'?

Comment: @JimG. Here I am. I haven't been following the election, but congrats to the new moderator and I hope the site fares well.

Comment: @Josh K: Thanks, Josh. Hope to see you around these parts.

Comment: Congrats World Engineer!

Comment: @AdamLear, this isn't a complaint; I'm simply curious. What's the point/policy/whatever for changing the user's name to "user removed"?  I.e. why would it be wrong to leave it as it was?

Comment: @RayButterworth The whole user profile was deleted (at the user's request), so it left a broken image behind. We could edit to replace it with some text, but it's kind of six of one, half dozen of the other at that point. (The same "user was removed" image is used in the election results in place of the flair as well. One of these years, we should come up with a better image.)

Answer (score 17):

I'd like to thank everyone here for making this a community worth defending. I am honored to serve. Come At Me, Prog!

Comment: That diamond looks on you ;-)

Comment: Congrats!``````

Answer (score 3):

We all love charts, right? Here's a nice one comparing this election's participation with the two previous elections:

[image]

...and here's another comparing this election's participation with all other 2013 elections:

[image]

...and if you prefer numbers from pretty pictures, [I got you covered](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Asxpisj1_dzYdE5tZjdZVVh5R2hDTl9hbmdITEFoUHc&usp=sharing).

Just don't ask me to interpret any of this, mmmkay?